# AWS CloudFormation trouble with VPC and Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to use below template generated from Cloud-former tool in my another AWS account but it gives me error each time.
It is simple template with VPC, Subnet, Routetables and IGW.

URL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-459239532405/cloudformer.template
Error: The following resource(s) failed to create: [rtb50d7b237, subnet3237ac6a, gw1, subnet47f0bd31]. . Rollback requested by user.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. Just be sure you're in `us-east-1`
2. Each account has it's own set of AZ. You can look for yours

   ```
   aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --region us-east-1
   ```

result for me:

```
{
"AvailabilityZones": [
    {
        "State": "available",
        "RegionName": "us-east-1",
        "Messages": [],
        "ZoneName": "us-east-1a"
    },
    {
        "State": "available",
        "RegionName": "us-east-1",
        "Messages": [],
        "ZoneName": "us-east-1b"
    },
    {
        "State": "available",
        "RegionName": "us-east-1",
        "Messages": [],
        "ZoneName": "us-east-1d"
    },
    {
        "State": "available",
        "RegionName": "us-east-1",
        "Messages": [],
        "ZoneName": "us-east-1e"
    }
    ]
}
```

I would try to change `us-east-1c` subnets to another zone in my template

Comment: Not sure but i think i have to add WaitCondition but where to add in this template that is what i am looking for.

Comment: i don't think any place of your template need waiting. Have you looked at resources tab in the details? It should has more explanation about the errors.

Comment: Thank you, for information looking to resource tab i came to know that one of route was not having physical id so it was Roll back.